# Get distinct values for certain date from Cassandra DB

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, distinct, cql

I have created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderHistory (
  status varchar,
  id bigint,
  ordtype varchar, 
  side varchar, 
  instrument varchar,
  exrate double, 
  dt timestamp, 
  primary key((id,dt),status)
)
```

And filled my table with orders(screenshot)

I should execute a query to count distinct ids for certain day. For instance, it's on SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM OH.OrderHistory WHERE dt LIKE '%01/10/18%'
```

I tried many cql but in vain

It should looks like

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) FROM oh.orderhistory WHERE dt <= '2018-01-11 00:00:00' and dt >= '2018-01-10 00:00:00' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

on SQL but it doesn't work

[image: Orders]

Comment: please note, that in Cassandra `select * from ...` won't work on big datasets...

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra isn't designed for such kind of queries - because of its distributed nature, it doesn't support scans on arbitrary columns. If you perform some query, then you need to model your tables around this query(-ies). For example, in your example (as I understand, it's "find all orders for given day"), you can use `date` type instead of `timestamp` as partition key (but you need to make sure that you won't have millions of orders).

In such case you may need to use Spark, for example, for scanning through whole data & perform aggregations.